# Why GSUB does not work in AWK?

Tags: awk

I am trying to do a substitution with AWK by passing two variables that are going to be used in the substitution.

My initial try was:

```
FILE=a
cat $FILE | awk -v var1="$Linea_SF" -v var2="$Linea_EF" '{gsub(/var1/,"var2");}1'
```

the content of the file a is:

```
H224:N3-H224:N3H
```

The variables are:

```
Linea_SF=H224:N3-H224:N3H
Linea_EF=H224:N3-S105:O4H
```

But, it does not make the desired substitution.

```
Why?
```

Is any other way to do it? like sed or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `/var1/` and `"var2"` are, respectively, a *regexp constant* and a *string literal*.

You can use the value of `var1` as a *dynamic regexp* or *computed regexp* and the value of `var2` as a replacement string by writing `gsub(var1,var2)` i.e.

```
$ awk -v var1="$Linea_SF" -v var2="$Linea_EF" '{gsub(var1,var2);}1' "$FILE"
H224:N3-S105:O4H
```

(you don't need `cat ... |` since `awk` can read files directly).